# pageToOverride Chrome extension - toggle on or off use of pageToOverride in options

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension.  I set it up so that it overrides the default tab.  The manifest is set at:

```
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
        "newtab": "newTab.html"
      },
```

It works as expected.  The one thing is that I would like to make it possible for the extension user to toggle use of newTab on and off in the options.html.

My options.html already works with a background script to adjust how the extension interacts with other variables.

Is it possible for a chrome extension to turn this override feature on and off?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `tab` change listener, which will fire when tabs update using the [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated). (But you need [tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) permission for that).

Then you can just check if the URL is `chrome://newtab` and if it is and the checkbox is selected, then using [`chrome.tabs.update()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) relocate them to another page.

Comment: yeah, good option.  hoping for a way to turn off the override though

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such way for now :(